# Replacing quotes in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I have this below incoming xml where i have `&quot;` instead of `"`. How can I replace those with `"`. please let me know

Input XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:PDM xmlns:ns1="http://example.com">
   <ns1:ds><Details ID=&quot;3453636&quot; Add=""/></ns1:ds>
  </ns1:PDM>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Expected Output:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:PDM xmlns:ns1="http://example.com">
   <ns1:ds><Details ID="3453636" Add=""/></ns1:ds>
  </ns1:PDM>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: What you have posted there with `<Details ID=&quot;3453636&quot; Add=""/>` is not well-formed XML so don't expect to be able to manipulate it with XML tools like XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

Your input text is not a valid XML, so XSLT will refuse to process it.

Instead you can use e.g. the following *Perl* one-liner script:

```
perl -pe "s/&quot;/\"/g" -i.bak your_file.xml
```

Of course, you must have *Perl* installed.

Replace *your_file.xml* with the actual name of your file.

This command will replace the input file with the changed content
and the original (input) content will be saved as *your_file.xml.bak*.